# Problem coming up with appropriate Regex expression

Tags: java, regex

I need to match text similar to the following text in an if statement.

```
REG#John Smith#14102245862#7 johns road new york#John Anthony Smith
```

The expression is meant to match a `REG` keyword at the beginning of the string then username followed by an account number composed of numbers with no specific restriction on the number of digits, then the address and lastly the name of the individual the address is registered to.

The Regex expression I had come up with is not working. The regex expression is below:

```
^REG\#\w\#[0-9]\#\w\#\w
```

May you kindly assist in showing me where I went wrong and how to make it work.
Thank you in advance

Comment: You might also want to split the string at `#`, this does not use regex tough

Comment: What are the expected results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you don't use quantifiers (`*` or `+`) and space is not included within `\w` which stands for `[A-Za-z0-9_]`. The character `#` does not need to be escaped (at least as far as I know in Java). Try the following [Regex](https://regex101.com/r/HgiRGC/1):

```
^REG#[\w ]+#\d+#[\w ]+#[\w ]+
```

- `^REG` matches the beginning of the string (`REG`) literally
- `#` matches self literally
- `[\w ]+` stands for at least one word character or space
- `\d+` stands for at least one digit

In Java, don't forget the double escaping:

```
String regex = "^REG#[\\w ]+#\\d+#[\\w ]+#[\\w ]+";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `^REG\#.*?\#[0-9]*?\#.*?\#.*` , the operator `*?` means repeat until next slice of expression, in that case, `\#`